# Xcodeのjavascriptのインデント

Tags: macos, xcode

Xcode6を使っていますがjs編集時に正規表現で`\"`などが入力されていると、以降のインデントが狂ってしまうようです。
インデントが狂う原因がよくわからず、特定のjsを開いた時に変だという印象を持ってしまいました。

設定等での回避方法があれば教えていただければと思います。

Comment: 「イケてない」という表現だと趣味や趣向の問題になってしまいそうなお話でもあるので、より具体的に書いて頂けるとアドバイスしやすいかな、、、と思いました！例:インデントをxxxという風に調整したいがXcodeのデフォルトの機能では実現できない。それを実現できるプラグインはないか？/インデントをxxxという風に調整・設定できるエディタはmacOSXではどのようなものがあるか？、、など。

Comment: Kazuhiro Sakamotoさんもコメントされているように、「イケてない」とおっしゃっている問題の内容をもう少し具体的にシェアしていただけると回答しやすいです。その方が良い解決策が見つかりやすいと思います。ヘルプセンターの「良い質問をするには」のページを参考にして、質問を編集されてみてはいかがでしょうか。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

イケてないというのがどうイケてないのかわかりませんが、  
jsファイルを右クリックしてOpen As > Source Code で開いてるんですよね？

[image: open as source code]

気になるところはありますが、こんなもんかなと思ってます。

> OS Xでおすすめのエディタがあれば教えてください

私はWeb StormとかSublime Textをよく使います。
Atom.ioやbrucketsもありますね。  
あとは使ったことはないですが、CodaやText Mateの名前もよく聞きます。